# Github action wzieba/AppCenter-Github-Action returns error while uploading artifact to appcenter

Tags: android, react-native, github-actions, appcenter

The step in github workflow job, which is responsible for uploading artifacts to App Center, returns the following exception:

```
Using appcenter-cli version: 2.10.10
logFilter, request: {
  "rawResponse": false,
  "queryString": {},
  "url": "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/<***>/distribution_groups/<group name>/members",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "user-agent": "appcenterCli/2.10.10 NodeJS/v20.5.0 linux/5.15.0-1042-azure",
    "x-api-token": "***"
  },
  "body": null
}
Response status code: 401
Body: {"message":"Unauthorized. Correlation ID: <xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>","statusCode":401,"code":"Unauthorized"}
Error: Failed to create release upload for android/app-debug.apk. Backend response: Unauthorized. Correlation ID: <xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>
```

The workflow step:

```
- name: Upload artifact to App Center
    uses: wzieba/AppCenter-Github-Action@v1
    with:
      appName: <***>
      token: ${{secrets.APP_CENTER_TOKEN_ANDROID}}
      group: <group name>
      file: android/app-debug.apk
      notifyTesters: true
      debug: true
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had mistyped `group`